# selected option dissapears from view when i bind with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I am new to ionic/angular.
Default selected option disappears from dropdown view when I bind with ng-model as in (`ng-model="mycomment.rating"`).

If I don't bind, then it reappears.  My code snippet is below. Any clues?

```
           <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label" >
                    Rating
                </div>
                  <select ng-model="mycomment.rating">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option selected>5</option>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you bind your select element to your model, the selected option will be the one that corresponds to the value of your model (variable on the scope). If you want the default selected value to be '5', make sure mycomment.rating equals 5, by initializing it in your controller. You can even drop the 'selected' attribute in this case.

```js
var m = angular.module('myApp', []);
m.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.mycomment = {
    rating: 5
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <span>{{mycomment.rating}}</span>
  <select ng-model="mycomment.rating">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```